# How do we combine multiple csv files and plot the predicted and actual values on the same graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, plot

We want to plot both the actual and predicted values in the same graph after fitting a model using `RandomForestRegressor` as part of our data science lecture assignment. The two datasets we are considering are found in the following link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ajk8jbXM4TkdTeDQ

Our solution and attempt to the plot the values is shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 


df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "testdata*.csv"))))
#df = pd.read_csv('testdata1.csv')

for i in range(1,3):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)

print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)




X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)


modelPred_test = reg.predict(X_test)
ax.plot(pd.Series(index_values), y_test.values)

plotsInOne=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.Series(modelPred_test), pd.Series(y_test.values)], axis=1))


plt.figure(); plotsInOne.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
```

When i take only a single dataset as 
`df = pd.read_csv('testdata1.csv')` and apply the plots commands as shown above - it works perfectly fine

However if i combine the two datasets as

`df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "testdata*.csv"))))`

and apply the plot commands, it doesn't seem to treat the datasets as one and produces two lines in a single plot as in the following. The reason why we have two line plots in the following line is because the plot command is treating `testdata1.csv` and `testdata2.csv` found in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ajk8jGD1OxTTR0bXM4TkdTeDQ) even though are combined (concatenated or joined sort to say) using `df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "testdata*.csv"))))`.

How can we fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MaartenFabré, i would appreciate if you could have a look at this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just contatenate and then sort the new array so it has an ascending x-axis.
An alternative would be to use dots for plotting instead of lines.

Comment: I believe, plotting in dots instead of lines will solve the problem. I am sorting it like this if you have seen it in my code `y_test.sort_index(inplace=True)` and `X_test.sort_index(inplace=True)`. Or do you mean differently?

Comment: Do you want the data to plot as lines with different colors or to really merge it? If the latter, check if your sorting works as expected.

Comment: If we merge those files and dive it into training and testing set, don't you think treating it as one file (merge) and plotting as one will make sense? I have including the two sample datasets in my question and I would appreciate if you could also try incase it works out for you. Thanks!

Comment: It this neural network data? In that case better keep it separated.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, I believe you have to set `ignore_index=True` as in the following.

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "testdata*.csv"))),ignore_index=True)
```

Hope this helps.